# How can I get methods to work as callbacks with python ctypes?

Tags: python, ctypes

I have an C api that i'm interfacing with the python ctypes package.  Everything works well, except this little tidbit.

To register functions as callbacks to some notifications, i call this function :

```
void RegisterNotifyCallback( int loginId, int extraFlags, void *(*callbackFunc)(Notification *))
```

so in python my code looks like :

```
CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(Notification))
func = CALLBACK(myPythonCallback)
myLib.RegisterNofityCallback(45454, 0, func)
```

If the value of myPythonCallback is a FunctionType (i.e. not a method), it works fine and calls the callback function with the correct parameters.  If it's a MethodType, it still calls the method but then blows up with a segfault once the method is finished.

*edit*

To clarify, when i say function type i mean that myPythonCallback is defined as a function,

```
def myPythonCallback(Notification):
    ...do something with the Notification object i get passed in
```

When i say it's a MethodType, i mean a class method :

```
class MyClass(object):
    def myPythonCallback(self, Notification):
        ...do something with Notification
```

It blows up on the second type.

Is there an easy away around this ?  Or can someone offer me an explanation as to why this is happening ?

Many thanks,
Al.

*edit*

Digging a bit further with GDB gives me this :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. [Switching to Thread 1544567712 (LWP 5389)] 0x555ae962 in instancemethod_dealloc (im=0x558ed644) at Objects/classobject.c:2360 2360    Objects/classobject.c: No such file or directory.
        in Objects/classobject.c (gdb) backtrace
#0  0x555ae962 in instancemethod_dealloc (im=0x558ed644) at Objects/classobject.c:2360
#1  0x555f6a61 in tupledealloc (op=0x5592010c) at Objects/tupleobject.c:220
#2  0x555aeed1 in instancemethod_call (func=0x558db8ec, arg=0x5592010c, kw=0x0) at Objects/classobject.c:2579
#3  0x5559aedb in PyObject_Call (func=0x558db8ec, arg=0x5592c0ec, kw=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2529
#4  0x5563d5af in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (func=0x558db8ec, arg=0x5592c0ec, kw=0x0) at Python/ceval.c:3881
#5  0x5559ae6a in PyObject_CallObject (o=0x0, a=0x0) at Objects/abstract.c:2517
```

and the value passed into instancemethod_dealloc is :

```
(gdb) x 0x558ed644 0x558ed644:     0x00000000
```

Do you reckon this is fixable ?

Comment: Are you using cdecl or stdcall in the C API? I don't know what you mean by the distinction between function type and method type. Please could you explain more, possibly with code samples of the form that works and the form that doesn't. By the way, I have successfully created callbacks with ctypes so I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 16):

You can't, so far as I know, call a bound method because it is missing the self parameter. I solve this problem using a closure, like this:

```
CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(Notification))

class MyClass(object):

    def getCallbackFunc(self):
        def func(Notification):
            self.doSomething(Notification)
        return CALLBACK(func)

    def doRegister(self):
        myLib.RegisterNofityCallback(45454, 0, self.getCallbackFunc())
```

Comment: Ok, i see the reasoning behind that.  I take it that if I want to pass in a bound method from another class as the callback i need to do the closure trick ?  So is this a bug or just the way it's designed ?

Comment: Be careful to assign self.getCallbackFunc() to an inner variable (e.g. self.callback), otherwise func() will be garbage collected and the program will end with SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 4):

This may be a ctypes bug dealing with the magic behind setting up the stack for methods vs functions.

Have you tried using a wrapper via lambda or function?

Lambda:

```
func = CALLBACK(lambda x: myPythonCallback(x))
```

Function:

```
def wrapper(x): myPythonCallback(x)
func = CALLBACK(wrapper)
```

There's a third method using closures. If you're setting up the callback from inside the class, the method defined below should inherit the "self" argument due to scope - making it act like a class method despite being a regular function.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        def myPythonCallback(Notification):
            print self # it's there!
            pass # do something with notification

        func = CALLBACK(myPythonCallback)
        myLib.RegisterNofityCallback(45454, 0, func)
```

Comment: Hmm i'll give it a try, the code is at work, i'll try and replicate at home with your fixes.

Comment: one other thing - did your method and function have the exact same action? it's possible to manipulate data during the function to cause a segfault once returned

Comment: Hi, yes it's the same thing.  I'm manipulating a structure so i've had my fair share of segfaults whilst teasing that one out so i know what to watch out for.

Comment: Using the lambda and function methods above gives me 'bad argument to internal function errors : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 313, in 'calling callback function'
  File "/ms/.global/ln.w/user/a/alistaim/testing/ctypes/SwApiHelper.py", line 15, in <lambda>
    retFunc = DEALCALLBACK(lambda x: func(x))
SystemError: Objects/cellobject.c:24: bad argument to internal function

Comment: lambdas might not be supported as ctypes callbacks - you say the `wrapper()` one has the same behavior?

Comment: Yes, same error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 313, in 'calling callback function'
  File "/ms/.global/ln.w/user/a/alistaim/testing/ctypes/SwApiHelper.py", line 15, in wrapper
    def wrapper(x): func(x)
SystemError: Objects/cellobject.c:24: bad argument to internal function

Comment: lambdas are supported, but make sure that the lambda function is not freed by the garbage collector!

Comment: @lunixbochs the nested function workes like a charm! +1

Answer (score 1):

Its been said but the segfault is probably caused by the garbage collection of the method, you have to store the reference. I solved both the missing self parameters and the garbage collection problem like this.

```py
CALLBACK = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None, ctypes.POINTER(Notification))

class MyClass(object):
    def myPythonCallback(self, Notification):
        ...do something with Notification
    
    def __init__(self):        
        self.myPythonCallback = CALLBACK(self.myPythonCallback)
        myLib.RegisterNofityCallback(45454, 0, self.myPythonCallback)
```

Every new instance of the class create the bound method (self.myPythonCallback), so each registered callback is specific to the class instance. We've held the reference to the callback in the class so it wont get garbage collected. The CFUNCTIONTYPE callback is executed as per normal same as if it were a global function `<function_CFUNCTYPE>`, and its inner callback is the bound method `<bound method myPythoncCallback of MyClass 0xfffabca0>`. Bound methods execute with self.

**Note:** although it looks a lot like you could just use @decorator syntax, that won't work. Decorators on methods decorate the original method and then bind to the class, so the effect is self.myPythonCallback would be a `<bound CFUNCTYPE on MyClass>` calling a plain method `<function myPythonCallback>`

The closeure solution provided by @David-Heffernan was my inspiration,

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Keeping a reference and _not_ using decorators was the key for me.  Also my editor/lint complained about the `self.myPythonCallback` hiding the original method (although the code ran fine), so I realized that member var don't have to match the actual method name. E.g. `self.myCallbackPtr = CALLBACK(self.myPythonCallback)` and then use `self.myCallbackPtr` when registering the callback (not the actual method name). It may be clearer in the example to use separate names for those.

Comment: You are correct, it hides the reference. If you want to keep it for use by other python modules then do what you did, give each a name variation. I would argue for most instances, if you are interfacing a C library and this is a callback you won't want/need the direct method reference, only the C-types lib callback, hence hiding the old one is a good option to enforce it and eliminate the possibility of other developers using the wrong method.