# Increment Reference Counter for a CFUNCTYPE

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I have a library written in C. One routine from the library takes a function pointer, saves it to memory for later use, and then returns. I am trying to pass a Python callback function.

The problem I'm seeing is that calling this function later sometimes causes a segmentation fault. Here is some toy code I'm playing with. The Python code:

```
import ctypes
import sys

class problem(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("val",ctypes.c_int),("f",ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p))]

def change_struct_data(s):
    s.contents.val = 99

class UsefulInfo:
    def __init__(self,library_name):
        self.lib = ctypes.pydll.LoadLibrary(library_name)
        self.lib.create_data.restype = ctypes.POINTER(problem)
        self.data = self.lib.create_data(12)

    def setcallback(self,f):
        cback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,ctypes.POINTER(problem))
        funcy = cback(f)
        self.lib.pass_func(self.data,funcy)

    def makecall(self):
        self.data.contents.val = 0
        self.lib.use_callback(self.data)
        print 'val is now',self.data.contents.val


test = UsefulInfo('./libfoo.so')
test.setcallback(change_struct_data)
test.makecall()
```

The C code:

```
//gcc test.c -I/usr/include/python2.7/ -L/usr/lib/python2.7/ -lpython2.7 -lm -fPIC -c -g
//gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so -o libfoo.so  test.o
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct problem
{
    int val;
        void (*f)(struct problem*);
} problem;


int C_inc_ref(PyObject* obj)
{
    Py_INCREF(obj);
    return 0;
}

void pass_func(problem* prob,void (*funcy)(problem*))
{
    prob->f = funcy;
}

void use_callback(problem* prob)
{
    prob->f(prob);
}

problem* create_data(int n)
{
    problem* prob = (problem*) malloc(sizeof(problem));
    prob->val = n;
    prob->f = NULL;
    return prob;
}
```

After much thought, I suspected the function converted to CFUNCTYPE in the routine `setcallback` is being garbage collected. I modified the routine slightly with a print statement:

```
def setcallback(self,f):
    cback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,ctypes.POINTER(problem))
    funcy = cback(f)
    self.lib.pass_func(self.data,funcy)
    print 'ref count is',sys.getrefcount(funcy)
```

Not surprisingly, I get 2 references for `funcy`. I tried setting it to a global variable, to prevent garbage collection, and that seems to work (it does increment the reference count), but is certainly not pretty.

A better solution, I think, is to increment the reference count manually. But I simply cannot get this to work properly. I changed the routine again to:

```
def setcallback(self,f):
    cback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,ctypes.POINTER(problem))
    funcy = cback(f)
    self.lib.pass_func(self.data,funcy)
    #self.lib.C_inc_ref(funcy)
    ctypes.pythonapi.Py_IncRef(funcy)
    print 'ref count is',sys.getrefcount(funcy)
```

using either a call to Py_IncRef or a call to C code which increments the reference counter. However, regardless of which method to increment the counter I use, I either get a segmentation fault, or the counter is just not incremented (stays at 2).

Is there any reason why the reference counter to a callback function cannot be incremented? Perhaps I have made a mistake? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/7261524/1470749

Comment: Why are you using `pydll`? The `PyDLL` class is flagged to hold the GIL during a call, which you only need if the C library uses the interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cback` is a function that returns a wrapped function.  What else works that way?  Decorators:

```
# global scope, the callback type
cback = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(None,ctypes.POINTER(problem))

# decorate the callback
@cback
def change_struct_data(s):
    s.contents.val = 99
```

Now `change_struct_data` is actually an instantiated CFUNCTYPE object that will not go out of scope.  You can't call it directly from Python anymore because it has been decorated to be called from C, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The decorator idea seems to do the trick. Much cleaner than making artificial references. I still don't understand why I cannot increment the reference count on the callback function...

Comment: @Neither_8, it would work if you set `Py_IncRef.argtypes = [ctypes.py_object]`. You don't get an `ArgumentError` because `funcy` is a ctypes object, so you're actually passing its thunk pointer to `Py_IncRef`. This doesn't segfault immediately because the thunk code is mapped writable, but of course it's corrupted by this operation.