# Putting models in a callback function from ctypes library

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to setup an application based on the Google App Engine using the Managed VM feature.

I am using a shared library written in C++ using ctypes

```
cdll.LoadLibrary('./mylib.so')
```

which registers a callback function

```
CB_FUNC_TYPE = CFUNCTYPE(None, eSubscriptionType)
cbFuncType = CB_FUNC_TYPE(scrptCallbackHandler)
```

in which i want to save data to the ndb datastore

```
def scrptCallbackHandler(arg):
    model = Model(name=str(arg.data))
    model.put()
```

I am registering a callback function in which i want to take the Data from the C++ program and put it in the ndb datastore. This results in an error. On the devserver it behaves slightly different, so from a production server:

`suspended generator _put_tasklet(context.py:343) raised BadRequestError(Application Id (app) format is invalid: '_')LOG 2 1429698464071045 suspended generator put(context.py:810) raised BadRequestError(Application Id (app) format is invalid: '_')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function' File "/home/vmagent/app/isw_cloud_client.py", line 343, in scrptCallbackHandler node.put()
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 3380, in _put return self._put_async(**ctx_options).get_result()
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 325, in get_result self.check_success()
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 810, in put key = yield self._put_batcher.add(entity, options)
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 368, in _help_tasklet_along value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/context.py", line 343, in _put_tasklet keys = yield self._conn.async_put(options, datastore_entities)
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 454, in _on_rpc_completion result = rpc.get_result()
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1827, in __put_hook self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
File "/home/vmagent/python_vm_runtime/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1342, in check_rpc_success raise _ToDatastoreError(err)google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: Application Id (app) format is invalid: '_'`

The start of the C++ program is triggered by a call to a Request handler but runs in the background and accepts incoming data which should be processed in the callback.

**Update:** As Tim pointed out already it seems that the context of the wsgi handler is lost. Most likely the solution here would be to create the application context somehow.

Comment: Much of the answer is in the stacktrace - '(Application Id (app) format is invalid: '_')'  When a key is constructed one of it's elements is the application id.  My guess is in the context of the callback the environment setup by the wsgi handler is no longer present.  Log env in your callback and compare it prior to running you ctypes code.  See if you can put things into thread local storage before calling into ctypes and see if that is retrievable in the call back.  I have a feeling what you are trying to do won't work because the the way the datastore libs work.

Comment: i think you brought me to the right track, there is nothing in `os.environ`, i think i have to create the context somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I am only guessing what is my problem and i want to tell what i did to solve it.

The execution context of the callback functions is somewhat different than the rest of the python application. Any asynchronous operation in the callback fails. I tried doing an http call or saving it to the datastore. The operations never finish and after 60s the application shows an error that they crashed. I guess this is because how the python manages the execution and the corresponding memory allocation.

I was able to execute the callback in an object's context by wrapping it in a closure within a class. This wasnt really the problem but the solution can be found in this answer: [How can I get methods to work as callbacks with python ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259794/how-can-i-get-methods-to-work-as-callbacks-with-python-ctypes)

For my solution i am now using a combination of cloud-endpoints on another module and background threads on the ctypes-module.

Within the C-Callback i start a background thread, which is able to do asynchronous work

```
# Start a background thread using the background thread service from GAE
background_thread.start_new_background_thread(putData, [name, value])
```

And here the simple task it executes:

```
# Here i call my cloud-endpoints
def putData(name, value):
    body = {
        'name' : 'name',
        'value' : int(value)
    }
    res = service.objects().create(body=body).execute()
```

Of course i need to do error handling and additional stuff, but for me this is a good solution.

*Note: Adding models to the datastore in the bg thread failed because the environment in the bg thread is different from the application and the app id was not set.*