# Managed VM Background thread loses environment

Tags: python, multithreading, google-app-engine

I am having some problems using [Background Threads](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/background_thread) in a [Managed VM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/managed-vms/) in Google App Engine.

I am getting callbacks from a library linked via Ctypes which need to be executed in the background as I am explaining in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795454/putting-models-in-a-callback-function-from-ctypes-library/29821541#29821541).

The problem is: The Application loses its execution context (wsgi application) and is missing environment variables like the Application id. Without those I cannot make calls to the database as they fail.

I do call the background thread like

```
background_thread.start_new_background_thread(saveItemsToDatabase, [])
```

Is there a way to copy the environment to the background thread or maybe execute the task in a different context?

**Update:** The traceback which makes it already clear what the problem is:

```
_ToDatastoreError(err)google.appengine.api.datastore_errors.BadRequestError: Application Id (app) format is invalid: '_'
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. `I cannot make calls to the database as they fail.` - How do they fail? Do you receive an error? If so, what is it? Include the entire traceback.

Comment: As is already explained they fail because the execution context is lost and environment variables are missing (e.g. App ID). I will add the traceback in the question (was already in the linked question).

Comment: As already stated, `It doesn't work` aka `They fail` is not specific enough. Its nice you included the traceback in another post, but its *not in this post* which is required for a question on SO. Perhaps you should take a minute and read up on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) a question.

Comment: yes that might be, but the question was not about why the saving fails, the question is already far more specific. I already identified the problem, that is why i did not include the traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

application context is thread local in appengine when created through standard app handler. Remember the applications in appengine run in python27 with thread enabled already have threads.  So each wsgi call then environment variables has to be thread local, or information would leak between handled requests.

This means that additional threads you create will need to be passed the app context explicitly.

In fact when you start reading the docs on background threads it is pretty clear about what is going on, https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Background_threads  - **A background thread's os.environ and logging entries are independent of those of the spawning thread.**

So you have to copy the env (os.environ) or the parts you need and pass it to the thread as arguments.  The problem may not be limited to **appid** you may find thats only the first thing missing.  For instance if you use **namespaces**.

Comment: okay understood, can you give me a quick hint how to pass the context?