# pyqt instance method inside ctypes

Tags: python, class, pyqt, ctypes, typeerror

So I'm not entirely sure how to ask this question as I'm interacting with parts of another person's code http://pb.lericson.se/p/FpbYhX/ which uses ctypes, and I can't find any other answer that quite does it (This is close:
[How can I get methods to work as callbacks with python ctypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259794/how-can-i-get-methods-to-work-as-callbacks-with-python-ctypes) ). At any rate, here it goes.

So I want to run the above code inside a QThread class so I can pass a pyqtSignal with the relevant information back to my main program, but I cannot figure out how to overcome the following error:

```
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: expected CFunctionType instance instead of instance method
```

I only really know python, and haven't ever interacted with cTypes before just now. Below is the broader class from which this code is drawn (this is basically just me copying most of the code from the link file into a QThread class). The problem occurs 17 lines up from the bottom. As far as I can tell, python is unhappy with me using "self.my_callback" inside the "self.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback" because my_callback is an instance method. That's all well and good, but how do I make this instance method into a CFunctionType while still keeping it within my class?

```
class Handler(QThread):
  trackPadTouched = pyqtSignal(str)
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Handler, self).__init__(parent)
    self.parent = parent
    print self.parent
    global MTFunctions
    MTFunctions = MTFunctions(parent=self)
    self.parent = parent
    CFArrayRef = ctypes.c_void_p
    CFMutableArrayRef = ctypes.c_void_p
    CFIndex = ctypes.c_long

    self.MultitouchSupport =     ctypes.CDLL("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/MultitouchSupport")

    self.CFArrayGetCount = self.MultitouchSupport.CFArrayGetCount
    self.CFArrayGetCount.argtypes = [CFArrayRef]
    self.CFArrayGetCount.restype = CFIndex

    self.CFArrayGetValueAtIndex = self.MultitouchSupport.CFArrayGetValueAtIndex
    self.CFArrayGetValueAtIndex.argtypes = [CFArrayRef, CFIndex]
    self.CFArrayGetValueAtIndex.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

    MTDeviceCreateList = self.MultitouchSupport.MTDeviceCreateList
    MTDeviceCreateList.argtypes = []
    MTDeviceCreateList.restype = CFMutableArrayRef
    MTDataRef = ctypes.POINTER(MTData)



    MTDeviceRef = ctypes.c_void_p

    self.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback = self.MultitouchSupport.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback
    self.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback.argtypes = [MTDeviceRef, ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int, MTDataRef, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_int)]
    self.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback.restype = None

    MTDeviceStart = self.MultitouchSupport.MTDeviceStart
    MTDeviceStart.argtypes = [MTDeviceRef, ctypes.c_int]
    MTDeviceStart.restype = None


    devices = self.MultitouchSupport.MTDeviceCreateList()
    num_devices = self.CFArrayGetCount(devices)
    print "num_devices =", num_devices
    for i in xrange(num_devices):
        device = self.CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(devices, i)
        print "device #%d: %016x" % (i, device)
        self.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback(device, self.my_callback)
        self.MTDeviceStart(device, 0)

  def my_callback(self, device, data_ptr, n_fingers, timestamp, frame):
    #print threading.current_thread(), device, data_ptr, n_fingers, timestamp, frame
    for i in xrange(n_fingers):
        data = data_ptr[i]
        d = [data_ptr[i].normalized.position.x * 100, data_ptr[i].normalized.position.y * 100]
        self.handler(i, d, n_fingers)
    return 0

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Handler()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested, but try this:

```
MTContactCallbackFunction = ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_int,
                                MTDataRef, ctypes.c_int,
                                ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_int)

class Handler(QThread):
  trackPadTouched = pyqtSignal(str)
  def __init__(self, parent=None):
    ...
    self.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback.argtypes = [MTDeviceRef, MTContactCallbackFunction]
    ...

  @MTContactCallbackFunction
  def my_callback(device, data_ptr, n_fingers, timestamp, frame):
    ...
```

Comment: `my_callback` needs to be a method that can call `self.handler`, so keep the version that's in the question. Instead have the instance `__init__` set `self._callback = MTContactCallbackFunction(self.my_callback)`, which keeps the callback instance alive with a Python reference. Then change the registration to use `self.MTRegisterContactFrameCallback(device, self._callback)`.

Comment: BTW, bumping the shared library refcount (i.e. loading it with `CDLL`) for each instance is a waste of time, as is defining all of the function prototypes in `__init__`, so you could provide a version that moves those definitions at least to the class level, if not the module level.

Comment: @eryksun Your method solved the problem. I'm going to clean up the rest of the program for speed now that I have a working model. Thanks!